# Rails: Compare 3 Dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display a Campaign in a dropdown only if the campaign is active. The campaign model has a valid_from and valid_until column (both date). Now I want to show the Campaign only if `Date.today` is between valid_from and valid_until. E.g. `valid_from: "12-13-2015"` `valid_until: "12-17-2015"`and let's say `Date.today is 12-14-2015`.

The code (which is not working right now):

```
<% Brand.all.each do |b| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:campaign, Campaign.where(brand: b.company).where('valid_from' && 'valid_until' < Date.today), :campaign, :campaign, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
<% end %>
```

The expected result is, that a Campaign only shows up if it's "active" between those two Dates.

Any Ideas how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
(valid_from..valid_until).cover?(Date.today)
```

or, if you want to remain in your style, this:

```
.where('valid_from <= ? AND valid_until >= ?', Date.today, Date.today)
```

Comment: I've solved it this way: 

`Campaign.where(brand: b.company).where('valid_from <= ?', Date.today).where('valid_until >= ?', Date.today)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the syntax and logic of this is all wrong:

```
.where('valid_from' && 'valid_until' < Date.today)
```

There are two seperate tests to do here.

Change it to

```
.where('valid_from <= ? and valid_until >= ?', Date.today, Date.today)
```

You might as well combine it with your brand test too:

```
  <%= f.collection_select(:campaign, Campaign.where('brand = ? and valid_from <= ? and valid_until >= ?', b.brand, Date.today, Date.today), :campaign, :campaign, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
```